# how to debug possible heap corruption?

Tags: c, windows-xp, heap-corruption

VS2008, C. Also using some pre-built libraries.
When I step through my code in the debugger and over the library functions being called, I get this:

> HEAP[unit_test.exe]: Heap missing last entry in committed range near
>   35c70 Windows has triggered a breakpoint in unit_test.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   unit_test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while unit_test.exe has
>   focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Update: I refactored the code and see that I get the popup when doing a printf(). I also get it when there is a free(). I commented out those lines and now when there is a malloc(), I get the heap corruption popup dialog.

Comment: you should be more specific: which library and which function are you using?

Comment: There are a few options available to you depending one what exactly your code looks like. If you're directly allocating and modifying heap space, then you can set a watchpoint in a debugger on one of your pointers and try to see if some of your operations are doing stuff they shouldn't, like overrunning a buffer.

Comment: @AlcoJaguar I am calling malloc and free (platform is Windows XP). did you mean placing watches on all the pointers?

Comment: @revani the library was in-house and written and built a long time ago. The problem is likely in my code.

Comment: I wouldn't say all the pointers, as depending on your application that could be an overwhelming amount of information to sift through. What you probably want to do first is narrow down your investigation to a relatively small segment of code where when you enter it there's no sign of heap corruption, and when you exit you run into your error. That would be a good place to set watchpoints on pointers.

Comment: @AlcoJaguar "no sign of heap corruption". Correct me if I am mistaken, but I thought the symptoms are seen far away from the point of corruption.

Comment: Depends on the code, which I can't see ;)

Comment: @AlcoJaguar update:  I refactored the code and see that I get the popup when doing a printf(). I also get it when there is a free(). I commented out those lines and now when there is a malloc(), I get the heap corruption popup dialog.

Comment: Are you using Application Verifier to test for heap corruption? Application Verifier is a free tool from Microsoft that helps identify resource leaks and heap corruption. You can find App Verifier at url: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20028 You can find out how to enable it for heap corruption and other things from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457063.aspx

It's the only thing I could think of that might be useful to you.

Comment: @StarPilot, great suggestion and thanks for the link explaining how to use it! I used it and found memcpy() was overwriting memory causing an access violation. I hadn't allocated enough memory. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't sure if you had already tried Application Verifier. It catches a lot, but not everything. But in case you hadn't, I figured it should be mentioned. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you start by using Application Verifier to test for heap corruption. Application Verifier is a free tool from Microsoft that helps identify resource leaks and heap corruption. You can find App Verifier at url: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20028 You can find out how to enable it for heap corruption and other things from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457063.aspx

It is often useful in these situations.